# Mocha, how to test async code without UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, testing, mocha.js

I'm testing my server-side api endpoints with mochajs and I can't figure out how to do it properly.

I started with code that had the following logic:

```
it('test', (doneFn) => {

    // Add request handler
    express.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {

        // Send response
        res.status(200).end();

        // Run some more tests (which will fail and throw an Error)
        true.should.be.false;

        // And that's the problem, normally my framework would catch the
        // error and return it in the response, but that logic can't work
        // for code executed after the response is sent.
    });

    // Launch request
    requests.get(url('/test'), (err, resp, body) => { // Handle response

        // I need to run some more tests here
        true.should.be.true;

        // Tell mocha test is finished
        doneFn();
    });
});
```

But the test doesn't fail because it throws in the request handling callback.

So I googled around and found that my problem could be solved using promises, and it does, now the test fails. This is the resulting code:

```
it('test', (doneFn) => {

    let handlerPromise;

    // Add request handler
    express.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {

        // Store it in a promise
        handlerPromise = new Promise(fulfill => {

            res.status(200).end();

            true.should.be.false; // Fail

            fulfill();
        });
    });

    // Send request
    requests.get(url('/test'), (err, resp, body) => {

        // Run the other tests
        true.should.be.true;

        handlerPromise
            .then(() => doneFn()) // If no error, pass
            .catch(doneFn); // Else, call doneFn(error);
    });
});
```

But now I end up with a deprecation warning because the error is handled in a different process tick than the one it was thrown.

The errors are: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` and `PromiseRejectionHandledWarning`

How can I make my test fail after the response is sent, and avoid having an 
unhandledPromiseRejectionWarning?

Comment: If at all possible, a solution without `setTimeout` would be preferred.

Comment: try to register an event handler for the `unhandledRejection` event on the process object. `process.on('unhandledRejection', (err, p) => {})`. and then show what's wrong here.

Comment: @Cr. What do you mean by "show what's wrong here"? What should I do in the event callback? I can't call doneFn() or rethrow the error.

Comment: log the error message and append it to your question, because `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning ` means there are something error throw in `promise`.

Comment: Yes the error is raised by the test that fails. It's an assertion error and would read something like: "Expected true to be false..."

Comment: `handlerPromise ` is a `pendding promise`, try to change to `promise function`. and in this code, how to guarantee `requests.get reponse` execute after `express.get reponse`?

Comment: Well, the `request(...)` part sends a request that is handled by the callback in `express.get(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
  it('test', (doneFn) => {

    let bindRequestHandler = new Promise((reslove, reject) => {

        // Add request handler
        app.testRouter.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {

            // Send response
            res.status(200).end();

            try { // Here, we need a try/catch/reject logic because we're in a callback (not in the promise scope)

                // Run some more tests (which will fail and throw an Error)
                true.should.be.false;

            } catch (error) { // Catch the failing test errors and reject them
                reject(error);
            }

            resolve();
        });
    });

    let sendRequest = new Promise((reslove, reject) => {
        // Launch request
        requests.get(url('/test'), (err, resp, body) => { // Handle response

            try {

                // I need to run some more tests here
                true.should.be.true;

            } catch (error) { // Catch the failing test errors and reject them
                reject(error);
            }

            reslove();
        });
    });

    Promise.all([bindRequestHandler, sendRequest])
        .then(res => doneFn())
        .catch(doneFn);
});
```

Comment: Oh ok. Your code is not 100% accurate but I see the point. I made a version  works.

Comment: I edited your answer with the working code. Thanks a bunch